# Use latex in rmarkdown presentation fails

Tags: latex, r-markdown

I have some Latex slides I want to put in an rmarkdown beamer presentation, e.g.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Me"
date: "8 November 2017"
output: beamer_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

\section{First section}

\begin{frame}{List 1}
\begin{itemize}
\item Point A
\item Point B
\item Point C
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
````

This returns an error:

> "C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS
>   presentation3.utf8.md --to beamer --from
>   markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash
>   --output presentation3.pdf --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex  output file: presentation3.knit.md
>
> ! Missing \endgroup inserted.  
>                   \endgroup  l.85 \end{frame}
>
> pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF Fehler: pandoc document conversion
>   failed with error 43 Zusätzlich: Warnmeldung: Ausführung von Kommando
>   '"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS
>   presentation3.utf8.md --to beamer --from
>   markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash
>   --output presentation3.pdf --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex' ergab Status 43  Ausführung angehalten

How to fix this?

Comment: Use `# Section 1` and `## List 1` instead of defining the sectiosn and frames with latex...

Comment: Thanks, this works. So it is not possible to use \begin{frame} in rmarkdown?

Comment: Pandoc interpretes these headings as frames. So if you use `## List 1` and you would create the next frame with raw LaTeX, then pandoc would not have ended the first frame. Thats where these type of errors come from. So it is not possible/intended to.

Comment: To better understand what I want to say just take a look at the rendered tex file you created.